# Extract hours & seconds from Django Interval

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following Django PostgreSQL query that calculates an interval;
`querySet = dbname.objects.all().annotate(duration=Func(F('date_start'), F('date_end'), function='age'))`

which gives me a date interval, evaluated as a timedelta when .values() is called.
Now I'd like to further annotate the query to extract the hours & seconds. Tried django.db.models.functions.Extract, django.db.models.functions.Cast, but can't seem to find a solution.

```
querySet.annotate(hours=Extract('duration', 'hour'))
ProgrammingError: function pg_catalog.timezone(unknown, interval) does not exist
```

```
querySet.annotate(seconds=Cast('duration', DateTimeField()))
ProgrammingError: cannot cast type interval to timestamp with time zone
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#extract

Comment: also proper field to cast to would be https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield